# Can't build "hello world" Xamarin app for Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "Javac" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.LongPathHelper.Normalize(String path, UInt32 maxPathLength, Boolean checkInvalidCharacters, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ZipArchiveEx.AddFiles(String folder, String folderInArchive)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ZipArchiveEx.AddDirectory(String folder, String folderInArchive)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Javac.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() XamarinApp1.Android
```

The name of my app is XamarinApp1; surely that's not too long?

This is an out of the box default Xamarin Android XAML project... no changes to the template; I just tried to build it...

Comment: Error is pretty explanatory: "System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters." Check the directory path plus name of project, that is the fully qualified file name.

Comment: Say hello to windows' weird directory length restrictions. Consider moving the solution to a higher directory, like `c:\Develop\XamarinApp1\`.

Comment: Hmm, the solution is at C:\Users\edkol\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XamarinApp1, and there's 2 projects underneath it; shouldn't be coming anywhere close to 260 characters... still, moving XamarinApp1 to C:\VSProjects seems to have fixed it... sort of? Now I'm getting all these errors in styles.xml saying things like "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'."

Answer (score 6):

Open the Android .csproj and insert this **PropertyGroup** replacing the **IntermediateOutputPath** with a short path in your machine.
The MSBuild will create the output file here **"E:\temp\MyApp"**.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>E:\temp\MyApp</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

if you want see more about this error take a look at:

[How do I resolve a PathTooLongException error?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/path-too-long-exception)

[Shorter Internal Path Names (Experimental)](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.0/#Shorter_Internal_Path_Names_Experimental)